# java.lang.outofmemoryerror in bitmapfactory.decoderesource

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an image array and their corresponding title:

```
int [] landmarkImages={R.drawable.oblation,R.drawable.eastwood,R.drawable.ecopark,R.drawable.circle};


String []landmarkDetails = { "Oblation", "Eastwood", "Ecopark", "QC Circle"};
```

I'm new in using the Bitmap functionality and I don't know how to deal with this. The Activity force stops and it shows **java.lang.OutofMemoryError**
Now I want to insert them to my sqlite database, however I get an error at this line:

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                landmarkImages[loaded]);
```

Here is the method where it is located:

```
Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");


    for(int loaded=0; loaded <=landmarkDetails.length;loaded++){

        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                landmarkImages[loaded]);

        // convert bitmap to byte
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
        Log.d("Going to load images", "Image "+ loaded);

        Log.d("Goind to load objects", "loading");
        int ctr = db.checkContact(landmarkDetails[loaded]);
        if(ctr == 0){
            Log.d("Nothing Loaded", "Loading Now");
            db.addContact(new Contact(landmarkDetails[loaded], imageInByte));}
            Log.d(landmarkDetails[loaded], "Loaded!");
    }
```